Convexity of ratio of quadratic and linear function
Define $g(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{\boldsymbol{x}'A\boldsymbol{x}}{\boldsymbol{l}'\boldsymbol{x}}$, where $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)'$ such that $x_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1$, $A$ is real symmetric matrix and $\boldsymbol{l}$ is a vector with positive components. Both numerator and denominator are convex functions. Can we say that $g(\boldsymbol{x})$ is also convex?
I am working on proving that the variance of an estimator is concave which is of the form
$$K'D\psi - \frac{K'LK}{K'\psi}$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $1,2,...\ldots,n$, $K$ is vector belonging to the unit simplex and $\psi$ is vector with positive real numbers, and $L$ is positive definite matrix. Numerically I can verify that this function is concave.

So $A$ is positive semi-definite? If so, yes.

@RiverLi Thank you for your reply. How can I prove it?

You need to add your attempt or context of the problem etc. Otherwise, the question does not meet the quality standards.

@RiverLi The denominator can be treated as a positive real constant say a, thus the matrix $A/a$ is still positive semi definite. Is it the correct way of proving the claim?

Did you encounter this problem in your research? You need to include some context (e.g. source) of your problem. Otherwise, some users will vote to close your question due to lack of context etc. You can edit your question by adding some context, attempt.

@RiverLi I have added the context.

convex quadratic over linear is convex, you can find this in Boyd's convex optimization book

Remark. I learned this trick from @A.Γ.;
Assume that $A$ is real symmetric PSD.
Let
$$f(x, t) := - (l'x) t^2 + 2t \sqrt{x'Ax}.$$
Clearly, for each $t \ge 0$, $f(x, t)$ is convex in $x$.
Thus,
$\sup_{t\ge 0} f(x, t)$  is convex in $x$.
See Page 81, [1]. We have
$$\sup_{t\ge 0} f(x, t)
= \frac{x'Ax}{l'x}.$$
Thus, $\frac{x'Ax}{l'x}$ is convex.
References
[1] Boyd and Vandenberghe, "Convex optimization".
http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Thank you very much.

@SPSINGH You are welcome. Alternatively, you may calculate the second derivative.

similar to your answer, is there any trick to prove that the product of a positive linear function and a positive convex function is convex?

@SPSINGH Perhaps in general the product is not convex?

@SPSINGH. Generally, the prod is not convex. e.g. $f(x) = x(x-1)^2$ in the domain $x>=0$.
