Maximisation of a function involving the ratio of quadratic and linear forms
I have a function to maximise
$\boldsymbol{x}'A\boldsymbol{a} - \frac{\boldsymbol{x}'B\boldsymbol{x}}{\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{b}} - \frac{\boldsymbol{x}'C\boldsymbol{x}}{\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{c}}$ where $A,B,C$ are real symmetric positive semi definite matrices and $\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b}, \boldsymbol{c}$ are vectors with positive entries. Further, $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = 1$, $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$, and $B = D\boldsymbol{b}\boldsymbol{b}'D$ and $C = D\boldsymbol{c}\boldsymbol{c}'D$ where $D = diag\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
I derived the derivative of this function which is complicated. Is there any way to find analytical optimal value of  $\boldsymbol{x}$ which maximises the above problem. I have also shown that the problem in hand is concave. The Gradient is
$$A\boldsymbol{a} - \frac{(\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{b})(2B\boldsymbol{x}) - (\boldsymbol{x}'B\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{b}}{(\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{b})^2}-\frac{(\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{c})(2C\boldsymbol{x}) - (\boldsymbol{x}'C\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{c}}{(\boldsymbol{x}'\boldsymbol{c})^2}$$

can you show the gradient?

@GBmath I have updated the question with gradient information.

there cannot be a maximum if $x$  is allowed to have negative entries... more precisely, if $x'b$  or $x'c$  can be zero  or negative.

@WillJagy Yes you are correct. I have modified the question.

@WillJagy Since B and C are positive semi definite. And the ratio is convex is proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4952681/convexity-of-ratio-of-quadratic-and-linear-function

@WillJagy Yes B and C are rank 1.

example showing how negative entries in $x$ cause lack of maximum.  Let $a=b=c = (1,2)'$   and  $A=I$   Finally let $x = (2 + \delta, -1 - \delta)'$  so that $x'b = x'c = - \delta,$   here $\delta > 0$ is small. But the numerators are modest positive reals near $4$

@WillJagy x is non negative. I have updated the question already.

Even if you can find the maximum of a single one of those ratios, the maximum of the sum is far more involved

@SPSINGH may not easy/possible to find the closed-form solution. Just plugin to a convex program solver to get the solution
